# Get the most out from a Akka app running on a standalone phisical server

Tags: performance, akka, scalability

Let's suppose we're facing a new VERY LOW BUDGET Scala/Akka project (a web services stack). From the requirements we realized that we can group the tasks to be accomplished by our project in two different categories not concerning one each other. So we can think to split our project in two different apps.

In case these two apps are deployed on a standalone server, I was wondering if there will be a significant difference in performance/scalability** between

1) creating two apps 
 
2) put all the tasks in a single app.

I realize this question may sounds vague but I'd like to gather some feedback on how would you face a very low budget project built on top of Akka in order to get the most out from a standalone server hardware (not "What can I get"), so I expect to get some general hints applicable to any standalone hardware configuration.

(**) I know the idea of scalability may sounds weird on a standalone server, here I just mean the ability to handle an increasing call per second rate up to the hardware limits.

About the choice of the software stack to use (Spray vs Play, MySQL vs Maria DB, etc...) please consider it out of topic. We'll relay on benchmarks.

Comment: The only big difference I can see is that 2 apps = 2 processes. This means that when you have two apps you don't only manage your multi-threading but the cpu time gets shared according to whatever the OS decides (which is out of your control), while a single app with more threads is more controllable. On the other hand, single responsibility is a Very Good Thing. Vague answer to a vague question though :/

Comment: Vague answer of course, but a good starting point: my dilemma is "could be worth to turn down a neat separation of concerns (2 apps) in order to gain a bit better performance?"

Comment: I'd say no. The performance gain would be negligible in most cases. I'd much rather suggest creating 3 projects instead: app1, app2 and a common library to limit code duplication and ease updates.

Answer (score 1):

No, there would not be any source of "significant difference in performance/scalability".  There are only 2 ways in which a single `ActorSystem` in one application would have different performance characteristics than 2 separate systems in 2 separate applications:

1. Process Handling: As mentioned in the comments adding a second application would place more responsibility for CPU resource management onto the OS.  This however is a trivial amount of additional work since modern OS kernels behave almost the exact same when managing `n` applications compared to managing `n+1` applications.
2. Thread Pool Management: The ActorSystem is responsible for [dispatching work from `Actor` instances to an underlying thread pool](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html).  If the ActorSystem has a more complete understanding of work distribution amongst your Actor set then it would be more efficient at allocating the thread pool's resources.  However, the OS is pretty good at resource allocation too so the performance improvement should be negligible.